# when doing docker compose, is it possible to keep previous docker composition

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, docker-container

I have a docker composition with 3 contaiers. I would like to keep these 3 containers and recreate another instance of the composition, without reusing, nor deleteing the previous 3 containers. Conceptually, would be like running 2 intances of the same application, where the application is the composition.
Docker compose always tries to reuse the existing containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a different project for your compose file.

```
docker-compose -p namespace2 up -d
```

By default, the project name is the name of the directory where your docker-compose is. You could also create a new dir and copy your compose file into it. It's the same as specifying `-p`. It basically specifies the namespace for the objects in your compose file.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also pass a project name using the `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable